# Make user fill parameters in a defined order?

Tags: abap, dynpro, sap-selection-screens

I have a selection-screen block with two parameters (p1 & p2). I want to force the user to fill the p1 first and then the p2...

Someone can help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would greyout the 2nd parameter (input = 0) and display a hint to the right that Parameter 1 needs to bw filled first.

Comment: THanks you,  it ll work, now i have to find how to ungrey it whenthe 1st field is filled

Comment: @d4xtian Note that it won't be possible until the user presses enter, because otherwise there is no communication between frontend and backend.

Comment: When it click entrer the 2nd field didn't ungrey...

Comment: Finally i use a IF statement to do what i want... when i find how to post my code here i ll update and share for others who could need it

Comment: technially it is not an answer, it contains no implementation details, only general approach